# Socket.IO server.origins always returns '*' as the origin value (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

I am trying to build a two way socket.io server/client connection. The server will remain behind one IP/domain and the client will behind a different IP. The point is to notify me when the server goes offline, in case of power outage or server failure. The issue I am having, is I am trying to secure the socket so not just anyone can connect to the socket. Socket.IO has a server.origins function that will return the origin of socket trying to connect. Their API documentation explains it like this.

```
io.origins((origin, callback) => {
  if (origin !== 'https://foo.example.com') {
    return callback('origin not allowed', false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
});
```

The issue I am having is whenever I connect to the socket.io server with socket.io-client the origin is always '*'.

Under potential drawbacks in there API is says:
"in some situations, when it is not possible to determine origin it may have value of *"

How do I get socket.io it see the IP where the socket connection request is coming from?

Once the connection is established I can use the socket information and see the IP where the socket lives, but the connection is already made. I am trying to stop rouge connections.

```
# Server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const chalk = require('chalk')
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const cors = require('cors');

const port = 4424;

app.use(cors());

io.origins((origin, callback) => {
    console.log(origin);

    if (origin !== '*') {
        return callback('origin not allowed', false);
    }
    callback(null, true);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Client connected...');

    socket.on('join', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('messages', 'Hello from server');
    });
})

server.listen(port, () => console.log(chalk.blue(`Express started on port ${port}!`)));
```

Client:

```
# Client
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io('https://"MY DOMAIN THAT THE SERVER IS BEHIND"', { reconnect: true })

socket.on('connect', (data) => {
    console.log("Connection successful");
    socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
});

socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    console.log("Connection error");
});

socket.on('disconnect', (timeout) => {
    console.log("Connection disconnected");
})

socket.on('messages', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I have the server behind a NGINX server using SSL, and connected to the server with the client on a different IP and it goes through and creates the connection, but the Origin is always "*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out you can use middleware with Socket.io with the io.use() function. I just wrote a simple middleware that checks the incoming socket ip with a list of approved ips.

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
    const ip = socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for']
    if (firewall(ip))
    {
        return next();
    }
})
```

And firewall is a function that checks if the ip is in the array of approved ips.